# Custom style following HTML form select field into rails code

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to style below dropdown select option using rails form `select` or `collection_select`

```
<div class="field">
<label>Gender</label>
<div class="ui selection dropdown">
    <input name="gender" type="hidden" value="Male"/>
    <div class="default text">Select gender</div>
    <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
    <div class="menu">
        <div class="item" data-value="male" data-text="Male">
            <i class="male icon"></i>
            Male
        </div>
        <div class="item" data-value="female" data-text="Female">
            <i class="female icon"></i>
            Female
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I go about it? Because I'm finding it difficult to custom style rails select helper.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is pretty difficult to parse your html into Rails code without actually working with it, but you may find a good start [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-select).

As you can see in that link, you can pass custom blocks for options:

```
    # A block can be passed to select to customize how the options tags will be rendered. This is useful when the options tag has complex attributes.
    select(report, "campaign_ids") do
      available_campaigns.each do |c|
        content_tag(:option, c.name, value: c.id, data: { tags: c.tags.to_json })
      end
    end
```

I think it is your way to go.